# How do i get rid of lot of flies (dead and alive) inside my refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

I went out for 3 months. I cleaned the fridge before i leave but now both upper and lower part is full of dozens of flies.There are just few foods there. I dont know how can i clean it. Or can i use bug fogger inside the fridge? Please help!!'

Comment: Did you leave the door open?  A vacuum should remove them from the fridge.  Any food will need to be removed before using chemicals and a very good cleaning before placing food back in.  If the door was kept closed, then you have a bigger problem, since flies/bugs should not be able to get in a fridge.

Comment: Grab the manual and look for section on how to clean the fridge. Fridges have compartments that can trap food, and it's just super nasty there. If anything went bad in the fridge and became liquid, or you spilt large quantity of liquids, it will certainly collect in those compartments and rot.

Comment: Is your fridge actually cooling?  I would think flies wouldn't survive at refrigerator temps.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem has to be a small gap somewhere in between the door and the fridges main body that is allowing the flies to get in.
I would replace the insulation strip going around the inside of the whole door. There is usually a strip on the body also, but putting it on the door should work.This can be just a piece of foam stripping usually used as window or door weather stripping as long as it will stay in place and leaves no gaps you should be good.
If you still aren't able to get a tight seal you can try adding a second strip to the door.
Other options to keep the door tight would be gluing down a couple of small magnets where they are able to help keep the door closed tightly or even a piece of strong tape on the outside.
These are kind of red neck DIY and not to pretty fixes, but they are cheap and effective. Your other option is to get a new fridge.

Comment: Replacing defective/worn out gaskets is normal. But just randomly adding extra? Not a good idea. Why? Because if you have enough of a gap for flies to get in then you have a **lot** of cold air going out/warm air going in - i.e., the refrigerator is not working very efficiently. That wastes a **lot** of energy and ad hoc fixes are extremely unlikely to fix it effectively.